# Can't connect via HTTP to dyndns.org-powered home webserver outside of router ... why?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, webserver

I'm setting up a webserver behind my router. I've done the following:

1. Router: Port forwarded 80, 8000, 8080 to the correct IP address (192.168.1.5 in this context).
2. Router: Enabled dyndns.org dynamic dns.
3. Started the webserver (Django's development webserver for now) on my box (VM-based Debian sitting on a Vista host ... bridged networking enabled) @ 192.168.1.5:80.

When I'm on another machine inside my router (e.g. my iPhone, my work laptop, my PS3 browser), I can connect to the website using the domain name ([mikerand.dyndns-home.com](http://mikerand.dyndns-home.com)). When I'm outside of the router, however (e.g. when my work laptop is plugged in at work or I set my iPhone to 3G instead of WiFi), I can't connect.

What's odd is that the SSH server running on the same Debian box allows connections from outside of the router using the domain name, so I know that the port forwarding on port 22 and the dyndns are working fine.

Question: what am I doing wrong with the HTTP setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Internet Service Providers (ISPs) block port 80 traffic (in that direction only obviously) to prevent their domestic/residential customers running web-servers that would cause the ISP traffic volumes the ISP don't wish to support.

Check with your ISP.

Comment: Bingo. I have Optimum and would need to get Optimum Online Boost to enable incoming requests on port 80 and 25 (email). Thanks much.

Comment: See if 443 is blocked (it likely is).  You should be using HTTPS in this day and age anyway.

Comment: I get using it for transactional stuff (which my site won't be doing), but is it common practice to use HTTPS for the general site?

Comment: @Begbie00: Look at the top left of your browser and the status bar, is there a locked padlock icon there? Few informational websites use HTTPS. If the *authenticity* of your website contents are vital to your audience, then you should consider buying a certificate for HTTPS. If the *privacy* of your website is vital to your audience, then you should use HTTPS (with either a self-signed cert or the more convenient certs from a known CA)

Answer (score 0):

Given that your SSH server is working, that would point towards some sort of IP based access control in the web server itself.   I do not know enough about Django to suggest where to look.